# What is this plant/seedling growing from hard, oval, mottled-brown seeds?

Tags: identification, seeds, seedlings

I found some seeds when running outside:
[image]

I planted one for curiosity and it has 4 leaves now:
[image]

Any idea what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a castor bean, *[Ricinus communis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricinus)*. [Seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricinus#/media/File:Seeds_of_Ricinus_communis.jpg).
If you have winter, they'll grow 10-14' (3-3.5 meters) in a year, with nice ball shaped flowers/seed pods. In regions without winter, they can grow to become sizeable shrubs, with roots that can damage foundations.
The entire plant, but particularly the seeds, are poisonous, containing [ricin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricin), the toxin used in the famous 1978 umbrella assassination of Georgi Markov in London.

They're often used as a background plant in temperate zone gardens.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot, no way I'm gonna keep it as an office plant